# MDB/ACCDB execute macro/function (with parameters) by python script

Tags: python, ms-access

I want to execute a macro/function code with python script. I have this code example:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
objAccess = Dispatch("Access.Application")
objAccess.Visible = False
objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(strDbName)
objDB = objAccess.CurrentDb()
objAccess.DoCmd.RunMacro('MyMacro')
objAccess.Application.CloseCurrentDatabase()
objAccess.Application.Quit()
del objAccess
del objDB
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\workspace-python\TOOLS\SHPTOOL\test.py", line 8, in <module>
objAccess.DoCmd.RunMacro('MyMacro')
File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 3, in RunMacro
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, u"Microsoft Office Access can't find the object 'MyMacro.'", u'ACMAIN11.CHM', 10183, -2146825803), None)
```

Then I try another approach, call RUN method:

```
objAccess = Dispatch("Access.Application")
objAccess.Visible = False
objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(strDbName)
objDB = objAccess.CurrentDb()
objAccess.Run('merge', "mystringparameter")
objAccess.Application.Quit()
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\workspace-python\TOOLS\SHPTOOL\test.py", line 58, in <module> objAccess.Run('merge', "mystringparameter")
File "<COMObject Access.Application>", line 14, in Run
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 287, in _ApplyTypes_
result = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(*(dispid, LCID, wFlags, retType, argTypes) + args)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, u"Microsoft Office Access can't find the procedure 'merge.'", None, -1, -2146825771), None)
```

---

And my MDB code, the 3 functions:

```
Sub merge(path As String)
    MsgBox "Inside generated macro!!! " & path
End Sub

Sub MyMacro()
    MsgBox "Inside generated macro!!!"
End Sub

Function MyFunction()
    MsgBox "You MUST select a Destination Folder!"
End Function
```

Thanks

Comment: Not really a python guy, but just pointing out the obvious: that error says your macro doesn't exist. Make sure you use a valid macro name. A macro is __not__ a VBA function. VBA functions are ran using `Application.Run`. Also, you probably want to call `objAccess.Application.Quit()` before `del objAccess`, not after.

Comment: Agreed @ErikvonAsmuth. I am a Python guy and an MS Access guy and I often have to correct folks from the Excel lingo of *macro*, specifically that an Access macro != Excel macro (i.e., VBA sub/function). [Macros](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/introduction-to-macros-a39c2a26-e745-4957-8d06-89e0b435aac3) are specific automated objects set apart from VBA.

Comment: Thanks, see now my edited post with more information and another approach.

Comment: See whether Access can find the procedure when you declare it `Public` like this: `Public Sub merge(path As String)`

Comment: @HansUp Public Sub merge(path As String)
    MsgBox "Inside generated macro!!! " & path
End Sub... error: "Microsoft Office Access can't find the procedure 'merge.'"

Comment: DONE!!! "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\MSACCESS.EXE" "bdwithfunction.accdb" /cmd "param1;param2;param3" and... AutoExec macro and... Command()

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
objAccess.DoCmd.RunMacro('MyMacro')
```

by

```
objAccess.run('MyMacro')
```

\o/